# Hide Window Title Text (Gnome 43)

Tags: gnome, manjaro, window, window-title

How can I change the text color on window title bars, in Gnome? The text usually indicates the application's name and I need to hide it.
Giving it the titlebar's background color should be enough, but I can't find where to do it.

I'm in Manjaro Gnome 43. The window title I want to particularly hide is Blender's (a non GTK app), but the idea is to hide it for all applications.

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

PD: I tried modifying the gtk.css file without success so far. I searched also in the metacity*.xml file of an installed theme but there are no colorcode references.

Comment: Did you solve this? I was using `Unite`, but it is not ready for gnome 45

Comment: Hi, at the end I moved to KDE. Its window manager is super versatile, it lets you even remove the top bar or keep above other windows with simple keystrokes, among other things.

Comment: I used KDE for 3 years before I moved to Gnome circa 2021. Since the, I haven't touched it, but I remember it as being relatively buggy and less maintained. Is that still the case?

Comment: Not buggy at all and with lots of reasonable tweak options IMO. I don't like their branding much, their logo a bit all over, also that google seems to be involved in the project funding somehow scares me a bit (don't know much about it). But it is the only that ended up giving me tons of options for managing windows behavior. Been there for a couple of years, didn't visit Gnome since then.

Comment: If google is funding it then I want nothing to do with it. Used to be good when I was using it. I might install it on a VM just to try it out.

Comment: I think KDE profits from G. funding in code camps, but I don't know really what that means in practice or the compromises involved. KDE just turns to offer good options for window management from the menu, to keep afloat, set startup position and dimensions, hide toolbar and real full screen, linked to proper customizable keyboard shortcuts system settings. Gnome was buggy for this and so many expiring plugins, but sweet. Still prefer Nautilus to Dolphin a thousand times. Should check it out again in the future.

Comment: I am assuming that KDE reports back to G regarding user habits in terms of what technologies they use and for what they use linux (i.e. Development purposes, for example). This way, G will be better equiped with information on how to structure their own OS (chrome OS or whatever it is called) to fit the needs of linux users. It is really dirty, as always, but they need this cause no Linux user would willingly provide google with a survey. Hell, I know some people who wouldn't tell Google which calculator app they use even if they had a gun pointed to their head.